# Apache Http Client - After 100,000's of requests, I start getting status code 400 bad request for all requests

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, ntlm

I've got some strange behavior going on and could use some help sorting it out.

I use the class below to download approximately 9 million documents from SharePoint. And for some reason, after about 4 million docs are downloaded, it gets stuck in a state where all requests fail with a 400 status code. I don't think there's anything special about the number 4 million. As far as I know it could happen right away but I'm not sure.

The code is pretty simple. Pool of HTTP connections. Nothing crazy.

I created a reproducer project of the code that I am using to access HTTP client:
https://github.com/nddipiazza/reproduce-400-errors

See the Reproduce400Errors class: https://github.com/nddipiazza/reproduce-400-errors/blob/master/src/main/java/Reproduce400Errors.java

If I stop and start the program again, it will continue just fine.

An important note: The authentication being used is NTLM. Could the authentication become stale somehow resulting in this behavior?

Has anyone ever heard of a situation like this? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What I would is first, make it repair itself when that happens, so at least your software can recover, then log the raw network request see what it tried to send to who. It could be SharePoint balking, it could be your lib corrupting a request field, etc. Could be a memory leak. Can you try a profiler ? No way for us to test 4M sharepoint download with your example, as you can imagine :)

Comment: Yep I'm on the path towards doing that. I don't think it's sharepoint's fault because if i stop the program and start it again, no problems. Definitely not a memory issue that I can see because the JVM is a healthy looking GC log.

Comment: @Pierre what do you have in mind for "repair itself?" lock until all pending requests are done then close/re-open the connection pool?

Comment: Yes, I know it's generic, but finding a way to make it continue, however dirty it may seem, like restarting the thing from scratch at the point it stopped, will provide you the peace of mind you need to then investigate the detail of the issue. 9 millions documents download sounds like a big number, it's okay to have a first mitigation, before a more difficult final solution. Totally generic comment, no clue "how" in your case :)

Comment: And about not Sharepoint fault, frankly it's too early to say: it could be able to track the connection and have an internal limit. Try visualVM or other profiler to see what happens in the java code at that particular point. It's usually memory leaking or array resizing taking more and more time: that happened to me last month on a custom collection implementation we use, that was doubling array size non-stop after 1G of data processed...